# How many different ways can you make a total of 33 cents with penny (1 cent), nickel (5 cents) and dime (10 cents)?

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many different ways can you make a total of 33 cents with penny (1 cent), nickel (5 cents) and dime (10 cents)?

I know the answer but I found it manually by listing all combinations. I was wondering if there is a way to derive a equation to solve such problems.

Comment: See [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/GeneratingFunctions.shtml) for a way to use generating functions to solve problems of this type.

Comment: One thing that can be helpful is to reduce to a simpler problem. In this case, you can reduce to the problem of making 30 cents.